# Organic solutions that corrode metals

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, metal, surface-chemistry

Most of the common organic solvents are regarded as noncorrosive, but  stainless steel can be attacked by formic, acetic, and propanoic acids.

[Corrosion of stainless steel by organic solvent mixtures, Alice Y. Ku , David H. Freeman, Anal. Chem., 1977, 49 (11), pp 1637–1638
DOI: 10.1021/ac50019a044](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac50019a044)

Are there some aromatic hydrocarbon that attack stainless steel? Which organic solvents can corrode copper and aluminium?

Answer (score 1):

Picric acid (2,4,6-trinitrophenol) is an aromatic compound has been used as an etchant in the past. Picral is an ethanol solution of picric acid and could etch steel. Look up www.metallographic.com/etchants/etchants.htm

Comment: This probably should be a comment.

Comment: In fact, I think this can stand well as an answer to *that* question. It would however, be really nice of you to be more elaborate on it. When was it used as a solution? What references do you have? etc etc.

Comment: Do you know any organics that can corrode copper or aluminium?

Comment: A lot of the strong organic acids like formic corrode aluminium. https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=iEeiQEeLOmYC&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=aluminium+corrosion+resistance+in+organic+acids&source=bl&ots=EJldV_Y-Rk&sig=9TLKDJBoelMHddrRFFLOopoeT3s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAWoVChMIzuDTof6RxwIVBpKUCh2edA0Z#v=onepage&q=aluminium%20corrosion%20resistance%20in%20organic%20acids&f=false